# HAproxy port 80 and 443 to backend:80 and backend:443

Tags: nginx, haproxy

How can I improve on the following config, to get haproxy to listen on port 80 and 443 and pass requests to backend:80 or backend:443 depending.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
frontend http
    bind    35.154.100.100:80
    default_backend http_nginx_pool

frontend https
    bind    35.154.100.100:443
    default_backend https_nginx_pool

backend http_nginx_pool
    mode tcp
    server nginx2 10.233.32.143:80 check

backend https_nginx_pool
    mode tcp
    server nginx2 10.233.32.143:443 check
```

Comment: What do you want to "improve?"

Comment: Wasn't sure but I felt there had to be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tested this on HAProxy 1.5 worked fine

```
frontend http-https-in
bind    35.154.100.100:80
bind    35.154.100.100:443

use_backend http_nginx_pool    if !{ ssl_fc }
use_backend https_nginx_pool   if { ssl_fc }

backend http_nginx_pool
    mode http
    server nginx2 10.233.32.143:80 check

backend https_nginx_pool
    mode http
    server nginx2 10.233.32.143:443 check
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.